# how can i get successive camera frame in android?

Tags: android

**I want capture successive shooting with android camera to get HDR image using 2 image.**
but my code is not working. My App is just shooting twice with no sound(no shutter sound), and no save file i have(there is no file).
First, I think that my file name was same. so, I changed my file file code like this,

```
    // Create a media file name
    // add .SSS for identity
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date()); 
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
```

Second, using synchronized and startPreview(). but still not work.

below is my capture code using "private Camera mCamera".

```
// Add a listener to the Capture button
captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
captureButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            synchronized (mPicture) {
                    // get an image from the camera
                    Camera.Parameters cp = mCamera.getParameters();
                    cp.setExposureCompensation(cp.getMinExposureCompensation());
                    mCamera.setParameters(cp);
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

                    // if i delete below 5 line then work correctly(but, just one image i can get)
                    mCamera.startPreview();

                    cp.setExposureCompensation(cp.getMaxExposureCompensation());
                    mCamera.setParameters(cp);
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

and below is picture callback method.

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    String TAG = "HDR_TAG";
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Can you give me some advice?
Thanks.
(I'm sorry that my english skill is bad..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using thread and endless while. See below.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get an image from the camera
            Thread t_1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Camera.Parameters cp = mCamera.getParameters();
                    cp.setAutoExposureLock(true);
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                }
            });
            Thread t_2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    while (takePicFlag != CAPTURE_SECOND)
                        ;
                    Camera.Parameters cp = mCamera.getParameters();
                    cp.setExposureCompensation(cp
                            .getMinExposureCompensation());
                    mCamera.setParameters(cp);
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

                }
            });
            Thread t_3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    while (takePicFlag != CAPTURE_THIRD)
                        ;
                    Camera.Parameters cp = mCamera.getParameters();
                    cp.setExposureCompensation(cp
                            .getMaxExposureCompensation());
                    mCamera.setParameters(cp);
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                }
            });

            t_1.start();
            t_2.start();
            t_3.start();
        }
    });
}
```

and use some flag for capture.
see finally{ }.

```
final static String TAG = "HDR_TAG";

static int m_idenValue = 1; // 사진의 이름 중복을 방지하기위한 변수

byte[] pic_data_1;
byte[] pic_data_2;
byte[] pic_data_3;

final int CAPTURE_FIRST =       1;
final int CAPTURE_SECOND =      2;
final int CAPTURE_THIRD =       3;

int takePicFlag = CAPTURE_FIRST;

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    String TAG = "HDR_TAG";

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            mCamera.startPreview();
            if (takePicFlag == CAPTURE_FIRST)
            {
                pic_data_1 = data.clone();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken, data : " + data + "\ntakePicFalg : " + takePicFlag);
                takePicFlag = CAPTURE_SECOND;
            }
            else if(takePicFlag == CAPTURE_SECOND)
            {
                pic_data_2 = data.clone();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken, data : " + data + "\ntakePicFalg : " + takePicFlag);
                takePicFlag = CAPTURE_THIRD;
            }
            else
            {
                pic_data_3 = data.clone();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken, data : " + data + "\ntakePicFalg : " + takePicFlag);
                takePicFlag = CAPTURE_FIRST;
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the image data continuously from camera by setting previewCallBack for camera.

```
camera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);

private Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) {

     //get the image data here and save it..


    }
};
```